# django: creating two models depends on each other

Tags: django

trying to solve quite simple problem, but I'm a little lost.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

class User(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

User is user who use system, log in, create persons, etc.
Each Person has info who create it.
Each User should be just one Person also, but able to create unlimited Persons

So the question how to properly create User (on registration) and assign Person?
I can't save Person without user, also can't save User without Person.

I think use person.models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True) in User model is not good design, because User has to have Person.

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: Is `User` a custom Django `AUTH_USER_MODEL`? It doesn't look like one, but on the other hand you write about creating it during registration. So I'm a little confused.

Comment: Yes, it's custom Django AUTH_USER_MODEL. Does it make any difference in model type?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `User` should just inherit from the `Person` model, since every User *is* a Person. Incidentally this would also resolve your problem - creating `User` would create an associated `Person` automatically.

You should probably [read about multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) to fully understand how this would work.

Furthermore, the `created_by` field should have `null=True` specified, since the first Person wouldn't be created by anyone, so the first object need to have the `Null` value there.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('User', null=True)

class User(Person):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
```

---

Also, since you want the `User` model to by used as the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` you should [read about requirements for such models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: Ludwik, yep, good enough, but...
Person is extension of User. User does only communication with system itself. User.model
'class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):'
Person.model is more complex. With relation to other persons etc.
So User can't inherit from Person.
Every user is Person, but not every Person is User!
Also Person.created_by could not be Null, Person object can be created only by some User. It can't just appear from nowhere. It should be tracked.
If I'm right, it's chicken egg problem :/

Comment: the only one way I found how to solve it, but don't found this proper way is: to create Person with created_by = -1, save User with that Person object and after update person.created_by with already existed user.id :)

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what the problem is. "Every user is Person, but not every Person is User!" - that's _exactly_ why User extends Person, and not the other way around.

Comment: Ludwik, for example Person's contacts list. You as a User create Persons with contacts, you as a User you are also contact. But you create a lot of contacts, all of your friends. Some of them will user the same system. So there 1:m relations User:Person also 1:1 User:Person. (1:1 is not subset of 1:m) :)